# How do I check for a boolean change constantly?

Tags: java, boolean, listener, observers

I need something to listen to a boolean for changes in condition so it would immediately change from false to true when the conditions change.

I don't want a timer for this action, I just want it to constantly check for changes in condition and update the boolean immediately. Here is a snippet of my code where I need to check for those changes.

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
author = event.getAuthor().getId();
memberIsAuthenticated = authTracker.containsKey(author) && new Date().before(authTracker.get(author);
memberExpired = authTracker.containsKey(author) && new Date().after(authTracker.get(author);
if (memberExpired) {
    if (event.getGuild().getRoles().contains(StartCommand.verified)) {
        if (event.getGuild().getRoles().isEmpty()) event.getGuild().getController().removeSingleRoleFromMember(event.getMember(), StartCommand.verified).queue();
            event.getGuild().getController().addSingleRoleToMember(event.getMember(), StartCommand.unverified).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the function that executes your action(as argument) and then do your checks over boolean at end, or at the start of that function.

Comment: Why don't you use callbacks? Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Listeners and interfaces is all I will say

Comment: The answer is in the question tags : listener, observers. As for how, need more context. See [mcve]

Comment: If your goal is to force the value to `true` at all times, why don't you just prevent the change to begin with?